# The vector bundle of an hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a compact complex variety and $V \subset X$ an irreducible hypersurface.
Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ an open covering of X. With $s_{\alpha}$ i denote the local equation of $V$ in $U_{\alpha}$.
I know that $V$ is an hypersurface so $V$ is a Weil divisor on $X$. On the other hand, due to $X$ is compact, $V$ define also a Cartier divisor.
How can i express the Cartier divisor of $V$ or the cocycle of $V$ in the vector space $H^1(X,O^*)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for maps from $U_{\alpha\beta} = U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to \mathcal{O}^*$ that naturally arise from the hypersurface. All you have given are the functions $s_\alpha : U_\alpha \to \mathbb{C}$ which vanish along $V$. What happens if you look at the quotients $s_\alpha/s_\beta$?

Comment: $s_{\alpha}=\frac{s_{\alpha}}{s_{\beta}}*s_{\beta}$ on $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$. So i can take as cocycle $\frac{s_{\alpha}}{s_{\beta}}$. But you say that i need a function $s_{\alpha} \in O^*(U_{\alpha})$ if i take $U_{\alpha}\cap V $ non empty this function is zero on this set so it isn't in $O^*(U_{\alpha}\cap V)$ .

Comment: You don't need a function $s_\alpha \in \mathcal{O}^*(U)$ at all! That would give you a cocylce in $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$ instead.

Comment: I have this definition af a cartier divisor:  $D \in D(X)$ is a couple of $(U_{\alpha},f_{\alpha})$ with $U_{\alpha}$ an open covering of $X$ and $f_{\alpha}\in M^*(U_{\alpha})$ for all $U_{\alpha}$. So in tha case of the hypersurface $V$ the function $s_{\alpha}$ is meromorphic but equal to zero on $V$ so it doesn't stay in $M^*(U_{\alpha})$.

Comment: Yes, but the quotients $s_\alpha/s_\beta$ *do* stay in $\mathcal{O}^*(U_{\alpha\beta})$, since the order of vanishing along $V$ of both functions is the same.